# Why is $x$ not equal to $75$ degrees?

Tags: geometry, angle, quadrilateral

[image]

Someone told me,

> Draw $B C$. Let $\angle D B C=y$. Then $30+2 y=180 \Rightarrow y=75$. Now, notice
> that ABCD is a cyclic quadrilateral. As a result, $x+y=180 \Rightarrow x=105$ but

I cannot see their logic.

Comment: Notice that $DBC$ is an isosceles triangle which implies angle $DBC$ is equal to angle $DCB$. Then use the fact that opposite angles in a cyclic quadrilateral are supplementary

Comment: Which part of the solution don't you understand?

Comment: Just to answer the title question: The angle at A subtends arc BCD, which is more than a semicircle. So that angle is more than a right angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As triangle BCD is isosceles triangle and angle BDC = 30, we get angle DBC = DCB = 75.

Join AC.

BC is common chord so angle BDC = angle BAC = 30.

Similarly angle DAC = angle DBC = 75 as CD is the common chord.

You can see the theorem here [Angles in same segment are equal.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle)

Angle x = angle DAC + angle BAC = 105

Answer (score 2):

The following may be easier: Since $\text{m}\angle BDC = 30$, the arc $BC$ must span twice that, or $60$ degrees. Then, by symmetry, we have arc $CD$ spanning $\frac{360-60}{2} = 150$ degrees, so arc $BCD$ spans $210$ degrees. Therefore, $\text{m}\angle BAD = \frac{210}{2} = 105$ degrees.

Comment: (+1) Sometimes referred to as the [inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle)

Answer (score 0):

Draw diameter from D , it meets the circle at E. we have:

$\overset{\frown}{EB}=\frac 12 [\overset{\frown}{EB}=60^o]=30^o$

$\Rightarrow \overset{\frown}{BCA}=30+180=210^o$

$\Rightarrow x=\frac 12\overset{\frown}{BCA}=\frac {210}2=105^o$